# Compiles in java but not in scala

Tags: java, scala

Why does the following statement compiles in java but fails to compile in scala

```
new ClientConfig.Builder("http://localhost:9200").multiThreaded(true).build()
```

Scala IDE says "value multiThreaded is not a member of io.searchbox.client.config.ClientConfig.Builder" The class in question can be found [here](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/master/src/main/java/io/searchbox/client/config/ClientConfig.java)

Comment: Tough one without more information. Are you sure your scala project imports the correct version of the library and not an old one where this method doesn't exist?

Comment: I'm using same jar in both the projects.

Comment: All I can think is to experiment with other Builder methods, with ClientConfig without Builder, etc., trying to get more datapoints about what works and what doesn't, in the hope that it will lead to a theory.

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding the project - when I tried to reproduce this with a simple example I got similar errors, which vanished when I rebuilt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple example works:

```
// Java
public class JavaClass
{
    public static class Builder
    {
        public Builder(String serverUri)
        {
        }

        public Builder multiThreaded(boolean isMultiThreaded)
        {
            return this;
        }

        public Builder discoveryEnabled(boolean isDiscoveryEnabled)
        {
            return this;
        }

        public String build()
        {
            return "BUILD";
        }
    }
}
```

Scala client (an an Eclipse Scala IDE worksheet)

```
object ScalaClient {
  new JavaClass.Builder("http://test").multiThreaded(true).discoveryEnabled(false).build()
}
```

Try cleaning and rebuilding the project - when I was writing this simple example I got similar errors to you, which vanished when I cleaned the project.

Comment: Any guess as to the nature of the crud that needed to be cleaned?  Do you think that it was created when you had typed part (but not all) of the client call?

Comment: I'm not sure of the cause - I presume it's a bug in the Scala IDE that perhaps doesn't recompile classes that have changed (I have certainly seen this before when renaming or moving classes) but I don't have any specific evidence...

Comment: Scala-IDE sometimes needs to be kicked